# Why does select with case and union return an empty array with node and sqlite

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I've got a problem with a sqlite query on node. The query with SqliteStudio is working, but with Node.js I get an empty array.

Here's the query:

```
const query =`
    SELECT 'telephone' AS type,telephone AS data,CASE
        WHEN telephone = (
            SELECT data FROM customers_verified_contact_infos
            WHERE type='telephone' AND data=j.telephone AND customer_id = ?
        ) THEN 'true'
        ELSE 'false'
    END AS verified
    FROM customers j WHERE customer_id = ? AND telephone IS NOT NULL
UNION
    SELECT 'email' AS type,email AS data,CASE
        WHEN email = (
            SELECT data FROM customers_verified_contact_infos
            WHERE type='email' AND data=email AND customer_id = ?
        ) THEN 'true'
        ELSE 'false'
    END AS verified
    FROM customers WHERE customer_id = ? AND email IS NOT NULL
UNION
    SELECT 'fax' AS type,fax AS data,CASE
        WHEN fax = (
            SELECT data FROM customers_verified_contact_infos
            WHERE type='fax' AND data=fax AND customer_id = ?
        ) THEN 'true'
        ELSE 'false'
    END AS verified
    FROM customers WHERE customer_id = ? AND fax IS NOT NULL
UNION
    SELECT type,data, 'true' AS verified
    FROM customers_verified_contact_infos WHERE customer_id = ? 
`;
```

I request two tables:

- customers, with some customer information
- customers_verified_contact_infos, with list contact information verified

Contact information can be in both or just one table.
The result is a list of rows with data, the type of data, and if it's been verified or not.

Now, the Node.js request:

```
db.all(query,[customer_id], (err, data) => {
    console.log(data);
 });
```

The data is an empty array and err = null.

With SqliteStudio, with the same query and customer, I get:

[image: Result]

I tried SELECT by SELECT, and with case I didn't get a result. I don't find anything on internet which can help me.
If someone can help or give me advice, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query has 7 `?` placeholders, but the array `[customer_id]` only has one element. You need to repeat it for every placeholder.

```
db.all(query, Array(7).fill(customer_id), (err, data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: You can also bind one value to all 7 by using `?1` instead of just `?`.